# Windows restart process reload options

Tags: windows, command-line, reset

I have such problem. I've got Hanvon graphic tablet on a dual-display system. There is an option in tablet settings to select a display to work with, but I do need an opttion to switch monitors on the fly without entering options.

I've found out, that there is some file HWTabletFind.hou that controls the options. So, i've copied two versions of this file - each for one display. And created a *.bat file

```
@echo off
ren switch.hou temp.hou
ren HWTabletFind.hou switch.hou
ren temp.hou HWTabletFind.hou

taskkill /F /IM Jwpen.exe
start  c:\windows\jwpen.exe  /runtablet
```

`HWTabletFind.hou` is a running options file,
`switch.hou are` the options for other monitor
`jwpen.exe` is a process that controlls tablet.

Now the problem: everything works fine, displays are switching. But when I restart jwpen.exe process, all my applications (e.g. Photoshop) do not see my tablet anymore. Tablet works, but in "mouse mode" - no pressure, no tilt, etc. If I restart application, it sees tablet again.

I think, jwpen.exe must run on application initialisation. If it stopps, app thinks, that tablet is disconnected and does not see it again on jwpen.exe start.

Is there a way not to kill and start a process, but to reset it in some way?

If I change display from tablet settings panel, everything works ok. So it's possible to do it via custom script, to run it via hotkey without opening settings.

Answer (score 0):

`AutoIt` can help to press and click buttons in a script, `Autohotkey` can do the same by a hotkey, and `SENDKEYS` via a VBS script can press keys in a GUI too.

Comment: One of them is not third party.